# On the use of 'even much' in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Now, though, Sanders has evidently decided that progressives will no longer accept impurities — or *even much* tactical vagueness.

I think the part in italics means that tactical vagueness won't be accepted in the same way impurities are not accepted. How should *even much* be interpreted in this context? Shouldn't be there a comma after *even much*?

Source: 11th paragraph of this [NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/02/23/opinion/bernie-sanders-trump-2020.html) article.

Comment: 'Now, though, Sanders has evidently decided that progressives will no longer accept impurities – they will not even tolerate more than the tiniest amount of tactical vagueness.'

Comment: Isn't even more incorrect in this context, shouldn't it be even less?

Comment: *[nor will they accept] even **much** tactical vagueness* = ***progressives won't accept even relatively small amounts of vagueness***. It might look a bit odd to a non-native speaker ***reading*** it (and incorrectly ***parsing*** it), but that phrasing ***sounds*** perfectly natural to native speakers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Excuse my persistence, but I find it hard to see how *much* can be thought of as *relatively small amount* in this context. No dictionary I checked did list  amongst its definitions of *much* 'relatively small amount'.

Comment: @Norbert While *much* normally means "a lot (of)", the combination of *even* with *no longer* gives it a negative sense, similar to "I haven't got much money" (meaning "I have *very little* money"). Sanders has decided that **progressives will accept very little tactical vagueness from now on**. A native speaker would understand the usage, even if it's somewhat idiomatic (and therefore not so easy to explain). :-)

Answer (score 1):

Copied from comments made before this question was migrated from ELU to ELL...

> <sup>(FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica)</sup>
>   *[nor will they accept] even much tactical vagueness* = *progressives will **only** accept relatively small amounts of vagueness* (they ***won't*** accept very much).
>    It might look a bit odd to a non-native speaker reading it (and incorrectly parsing it), but that phrasing sounds perfectly natural to native speakers.

.

> <sup>(Chappo Says SE Dudded Monica)</sup>
>   While ***much*** normally means "a lot (of)", the combination of even with ***no longer*** gives it a negative sense, similar to "I haven't got much money" (meaning "I have very little money").
>   Sanders has decided that progressives will accept very little tactical vagueness from now on. A native speaker would understand the usage, even if it's somewhat idiomatic (and therefore not so easy to explain)

Answer (score 0):

"Even much" is not a unit in this quote. The word "even" appears before the phrase "much tactical vagueness": consider "will no longer accept impurities — or much tactical vagueness". This "even" is an intensifier.